# Can I drill a 6” hole in my i-joist (not load bearing)?

Tags: kitchens, joists, load-bearing, hood

Hi I am in the process of installing a range hood in my basement and I need to snake the 6” vent through a I-joist to get it to a place where I can drill it out through the rim joist. The question I have is that all of my I-joists run left to right (see picture) but for some reason there is a small area where it’s running the other direction only for a short span.
I don’t believe it’s load bearing but for some reason the builder doubled up on the ijoist in that spot so I’m worried it’s structural.
Any advice greatly appreciated!
[image]

Comment: How deep (tall) are the I-Joists?

Comment: If the joist wasn't bearing any load they wouldn't have put it there.

Comment: I believe the i-joists are 16" tall. Its a strange setup I haven't seen in other parts of the house. I am not sure why they didn't just put another long span and put those short sections. Could it be that the width was too close to put another long span so they decided to put short diagonal sections with hangers to bridge the next span to the foundation wall? I'm kind of stuck at the moment with my install because I am not sure what I need to do here.

Comment: The most common reason for a framer to box out joists in that manner is to make space for a plumber’s pipes— very often a toilet in the room above. And yes it’s structural in the sense that joists are always structural. They hold up the floor above!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback RibaldEddie! The only thing above that floor is a gas fireplace and that's actually closer to the left (middle of room) and not where my red arrow is in the picture. I'm going to assume its structural but I can't seem to find any clear guides on cutting a 6" hole in that short of a span if I ensure its 6" away from the foundation wall. Would there be any risk?

Comment: The doubled up i-joist is carrying 1/2 the load of the two i-joists that are hangered into it.  The area to the left of the double is the area that was framed out - maybe the builder boxed it out for the 6" hood fan duct you are trying to run.   Who makes your i-joists and have you verified you can drill a 6" hole in the i-joist based on their joist hole chart?  Here is an example -  https://www.mavbldgsys.com/joist-hole-chart.pdf

Comment: It looks like the I l-joist manufacturer is Boise Cascade. I think I found the specification document but I can’t get a clear read on it. I think it’s saying for 16” I-joist you can make a 6” hood as long as it’s foot from the end? Can someone reconfirm that? https://p.widencdn.net/zyjnyt

Comment: Sounds correct - the hole should be away from the support end due to high shear concerns. Also, the center of the hole is preferably aligned with the center of the joist.

Comment: Unclear why you can't simply go straight back to (what appears to be) the rim joist between the short crossways I-joists, rather than over to the  rim joist to the right of them. That would seem to be the logical reason for that section being built that way.

Comment: Ecnerwal, I wish I could - unfortunately there is a large gas fireplace exhaust vent right behind there. I'm pretty much stumped at this point and not sure what to do about this. Appreciate any suggestions. I'm worried about drilling a 6" hole into that short span as someone did point out its supporting two short i-josts as well.